# why hyperlink is not showing/working in gmail after sending password reset mail?

Tags: php, html, email, model-view-controller

I am sending `email` from server for password reset purpose. For test purpose I'm sending to `gmail` and `yahoo mail`. The mail delivery to the `gmail` and `yahoo mail` both but the `return link` is `missing` for `gmail` and in `yahoo` shows `garbage` in the `<a>` tag.

I am sending

```
Click here to change your password <a href="localhost:4778/ResetRequest?id=25fafb03-9715-4003-80bf-e362259afa77">please click this link</a>
```

In gmail, it is showing

[image: It is clearly showing the <a> tag is empty which suppose to contain the href link.]

Need help please.

Comment: Your link is `localhost:4778/ResetRequest?id=25fafb03-9715-4003-80bf-e362259afa77`. How localhost will work in mail link.
make it a global  link

Comment: @ajaykumartak this is only for test purpose. in gmail it suppose to show hyperlink. then clicking the link will not take anywhere. the main problem is, there is no link to click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need http protocol in the href value. Otherwise gmail will not consider that as valid link

```
<a href="http://localhost:4778/">Some link</a>
```

Comment: Dear @Tom Marulak, thanks mate. u r life saver. this is simply brilliant by a small answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

URL you are providing is not correct, it suggests localhost is a folder, yet you are providing port number.

You are missing the protocol (http / https):

```
<a href="http://localhost:4778/ResetRequest?id=25fafb03-9715-4003-80bf-e362259afa77">
```

Comment: Thanks @M.M. if i didn't mark other answer as acceptable then i could  mark ur one. good luck mate.